# What is the right way to fix error NU1605: Detected package downgrade - log4net

Tags: .net-core

You do as follows:

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add-package log4net --version 2.0.8
dotnet publish -r win10-x64
```

And then you get:

```
error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0.
```

You can fix it adding the following to your csproj under PropertyGroup

```
<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1605</NoWarn>
```

But I'd like to understand the right way to get this fixed.

Comment: When I started seeing this for Microsoft.Primitives.Extensions, i just needed to update the the existing versions manually first.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no other option than the package owner to upgrade their references or you adding the  clausule in the csproj. Please see this GitHub issue for more information: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/907

Comment: That issue also [shows a workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/907#issuecomment-326092990) that suppresses the warning.

Answer (score 34):

According to Microsoft, this can be resolved by adding the following to your csproj.

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="3.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605#issue-1

"Certain combinations of packages which shipped with .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 are not compatible with each other when they are referenced together in a .NET Core 3.0 or higher project, and a RuntimeIdentifier is specified. The problematic packages generally start with System. or Microsoft., and have version numbers between 4.0.0 and 4.3.1. In this case, the downgrade message will have a package starting with runtime. in the dependency chain."

Comment: TSBTBA: This should be the best answer!

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer. It enforces the runtime to be of a specific version, and bypasses the Nuget version resolution algorithm, which is the culprit of the warning.

Comment: Doesn't it completely defeat the purpose of a .NET Standard 2.0 Library to have to force a specific framework to be used with it?

Comment: Note that if you add the Microsoft.NETCore.Targets package using NuGet, you will have the option of selecting the appropriate version, which is currently '5.0.0' as of October 2022.

Comment: This worked for me too. My TargetFramework is net7.0-windows and I'm using Microsoft.NETCore.Targets version 5.0.0. For me it was the ' PrivateAssets="all"' that made it work.