# Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, nuget, .net-core-2.0

I am experiencing the following NU1605 dependency errors in my **netcoreapp2.0** console application:

```
NU1605  Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Debug from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MyProject -> Colorful.Console 1.2.6 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.3.0) 
 MyProject -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.0.11)

NU1605  Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Extensions from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MyProject -> Colorful.Console 1.2.6 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.Extensions (>= 4.3.0) 
 MyProject -> Colorful.Console 1.2.6 -> System.Runtime.Extensions (>= 4.1.0)    MyProject

NU1605  Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Handles from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MyProject -> Colorful.Console 1.2.6 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.3.0) 
 MyProject -> Colorful.Console 1.2.6 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.0.1)

NU1605  Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MyProject -> Colorful.Console 1.2.6 -> System.Console 4.0.0 -> runtime.win.System.Console 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0) 
 MyProject -> Colorful.Console 1.2.6 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0)
```

I have tried referencing these package versions in csproj, but this doesn't fix the problem.  See csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Colorful.Console" Version="1.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommandLineParser" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotSpinners" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Debug" Version="4.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Handles" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And they do seem to restore fine:

[image: Package References]

The project is also referencing the **Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0** SDK.

When performing dotnet restore from the CLI, I also get the following error, which I am not sure is related:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters' from remote source 'https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myid/nuget/v3/flat2/system.runtime.serialization.formatters/index.json'. [C:\MyProject\MyProject.sln]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\MyProject\MyProject.sln]
```

I have no idea why it's trying to retrieve information about 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters' from our private company package repository.

**NuGet.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="mycompany" value="https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Stable/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
     <mycompany>
       <add key="Username" value="vsts" />
       <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="xxx" />
     </mycompany>
   </packageSourceCredentials>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

I also have the following NU1603 warning if this means anything:

```
NU1603  MyProject depends on System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.1.0) but System.Runtime.Handles 4.1.0 was not found. An approximate best match of System.Runtime.Handles 4.3.0 was resolved.
```

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: If you are experiencing this issue,perhaps on a different package, its probably because you referenced a library that references same package but a different version. Try updating package via Nuget Manager in the referencing project.

Comment: Although this is quite an old issue, I just had similar issues with System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives and System.Runtime.Handles in .NET 5.0. Both were pointing that I had an outdated version, like 4.0.1 and told me to upgrade it to 4.3.0. I just installed these libraries in nuget with the correct versions so:
System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives -> 4.3.0
System.Runtime.Handles -> 4.3.0
And it worked, the error was no longer there. Hopefully, I can help whoever will have this issue in the future.

Comment: My naïve case was I had updated references but forgot to push one of the projects. Alas the build server got updated and not-updated project references.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a .netcoreapp2.2 console application.

The project was building successfully. However, publishing was failing with several NU1605 errors.

The problem was originated from log4net version 2.0.8. It was referenced in a .netstandard2.0 project with the following dependencies:

[image: log4net v2.0.8 does not include specific dependency for .NetStandard,Version=2.0]

They were causing package downgrades in the projects referencing log4net. And during publish these warnings are treated as errors...

To solve the problem I added correct versions of these libraries via Nuget.

[image: log4net dependencies and additional nuget packages for version errors]

Finally, the publishing succeeded.

**P.S.** When I first added packages with the newest version of libraries, a yellow warning sign was displayed on the dependencies list as if the packages were not suitable for that project. After unloading the project and loading back the warning sign gone! (I'm using Visual Studio 2019)

Comment: I just encountered this exact problem.  I have a project I am publishing which targets .Net Core and .Net Standard.  I think this problem only manifested when I added .Net Standard as a target framework.  Adding those three packages solved the issue.

Comment: I am getting exact same problem with log4net. How did you change specific DLL dependency for it? My .NetCore version is 3.1.0.

Comment: You can search for the dll in nuget and install the latest version.

Comment: Yes, just had the exact same issue with log4net in a .NET Core 3.1 console app. I had to add those packages to my class library as well as the main executable project.

Comment: For log4net specifically, the Microsoft.NETCore.Targets library added to the solution fixes it as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712035/what-is-the-right-way-to-fix-error-nu1605-detected-package-downgrade-log4net

Comment: Updating "System.ServiceModel.Primitives" has solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: It was helpful also for migration from .Net 5 to .Net 6

Comment: Yep, this solution works. Migrating DotNet 7 to 8 right now

Answer (score 58):

> Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade

For the error **NU1605**:

You can use `<NoWarn>NU1605</NoWarn>` to clear the `WarningsAsErrors` in your project.

That because `netcoreapp2.0` projects have `<WarningsAsErrors>NU1605</WarningsAsErrors>` by default. Check it from Properties->Build->Treat warning as errors:

[image]

Add like following:

```
<PackageReference Include="Colorful.Console" Version="1.2.6">
      <NoWarn>NU1605</NoWarn>
</PackageReference>
```

Check the blog post here: [MSBuild integration of NuGet warnings and errors](https://blog.nuget.org/20170815/Whats-nu-in-NuGet-with-VS2017-15-3.html#msbuild-integration-of-nuget-warnings-and-errors) and [Unexpected package version warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings#unexpected-package-version-warnings).

For the error **NU1603**:

The warning occurs because `System.Runtime.Handles` (>= **4.1.0**) does not exist in the feed. Typically this is a package authoring error because the package depends on something that doesn't exist.

You can also use `<NoWarn>NU1603</NoWarn>` to resolve this issue:

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <NoWarn>NU1603</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note:You would notice that your project has another warning, notice the yellow triangle insignia on the PackageReference `DotSpinners` on Reference. That because the package `DotSpinners` is a .NET Framework project, not compatible with your .NET Core project.

Comment: good info, but doesn't actually resolve the issue it just ignores the issue during build. When publishing you will get runtime errors when these dll's are trying to be loaded. See Mert's answer.

Comment: It seems much more often than not, ignoring these warnings, building and running will be fine.  Yes, it's good practice to pay attention and resolve the core issues.  But in this case, these should remain as warnings and not as errors.  Perhaps this will get changed in future  versions.

Comment: I really, really don't like this answer. Silencing warning should never be a solution. Especially when there are alternatives.

Comment: I struggle alot finally just added the latest version of dll from nugget, then unload ->reload the project and everything work to normal. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

All of the above did not help me with my .NET Core 3.1 project.

The error NU1605 reappeared again and again after complete recompilation. All references to the version number have been correct in the csproj file.

What finally helped was to **delete the obj folder**!

Afterwards the recompilation worked without problems.

Answer (score 10):

Just had the same issue (NU1605) with `.Net core 3.1` and `log4Net`:

> error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Net.NameResolution from 4.3.0 to 4.0.0.

What I did is adding a Nuget reference to `System.Net.NameResolution` and install version 4.3.0, then I closed Visual Studio and re-opened the Solution.

Comment: For me, A Visual Studio restart was all that was needed. Odd.

Comment: same here. but problem is resolved in latest log4net nugetpacakge now. so i have removed it

Comment: @IanGibblet For every problem restart should be The first solution to try :D

Answer (score 7):

I ran into NU1605 with .NET 5 while trying to update a Nuget package.

The solution to Example 2 in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605) article worked perfectly for me.

In short, I only had to add

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
```

to the ItemGroup of the project, which was the target of the update (in VS, the relevant .csproj appeared when I doubleclicked on the "Detected package downgrade" error message).

Comment: This was the perfect fix for me too, straight from the MS docs no less!

Comment: This worked well for me just now. The package is listed as "Obsolete" on NuGet, but still does its job (it sets more direct dependencies).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you are using same version for build and publish
you can fix it adding 2.1.9 
in .csproj file under PropertyGroup this should match with your current settings version.
Ex:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>    
      <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.9</RuntimeFrameworkVersion> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Error which I got was:
NETSDK1061: The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.9, but with current settings, version 2.1.0 would be used instead.

Answer (score 5):

Something that I've run into that causes this error is having multiple references to the same package in one or more .csproj files. In our case, these references are to local dependencies in our own nuget repository.

This is invisible to a developer in Visual Studio, so you need to open the .csproj file in a separate editor.

For my team, I think the cause is a combo of a lot of churn in both a dependent library and the solution that consumes that dependency. For whatever reason, a git merge will take both versions in the .csproj file without raising a conflict. In several project files, I found 3 versions of the same dependency.

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone looking. 
We are getting this building Xamarin projects.  Open the project in VSCode and look in the .csproj files of the sub projects for the item group with the "PackageReference" elements and update them to be the same as the default.
I am still looking into why VS isn't doing this, but this will get you on your way.

Answer (score 3):

There are already a bunch of answers to the question, many of them fixing the problem, but I think the solution I applied is cleaner than everything else I saw online.

As stated, the usual suspect of the error in .Net Core 3.1 is some assembly depending upon a library requiring a `System.*` or `Microsoft.*` assembly.

When the build runs, everything can be fine, because the resolution of assemblies is using only project references.
When a "Publish" build is performed, with a runtime selected, the resolution of assemblies doesn't follow the algorithm used by Nuget when restoring, so the Warning creeps up.

From this situation, follows my solution: when we perform a build with a target runtime, we want to enforce that the correct runtime version is selected.

In the .csproj file, I added this:

```
<!-- adjust runtime and package version accordingly -->
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-x64' ">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="3.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The `Microsoft.NETCore.Targets` package, found at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605) (which has lots of info on the warning) is one of the solutions to the dreaded warning, and having it included only in the publish build keeps all the other builds untouched. The nice thing of this package is that it is *one* package, and includes all the runtime.

Comment: that didnt work for me.. so annoying this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a .Net Core 2.2 project using a .Net Standard 2.0 DLL in the same solution.  I had the errors reported for the .Net Standard DLL when I added several SeriLog packages to the .Net Core application.  I backed out the changes, then added the SeriLog packages one-by-one, cleaning and rebuilding between each addition.  This time there was no error...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best option or the way to fix this problem, but i had the same issue:

> NuGet Warning NU1605 (package downgrade)

My process of elimination was to make sure my project was:
1. Saved
2. Build Solution (ctrl shift b) (only error was the NU1605)
3. Right click project folder, click into Manage NuGet packages.
4. Click on Updates, I personally updated all packages.
5. (Step 2 again).

This was all i needed to do. Hopefully this was the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The GraphQL nuGet package I was referencing had a dependency to `Newtonsoft.Json(>= 10.0.3)`. The only solution was the following:

- Remove the GraphQL nuGet package.
- Install the latest NewtonSoft.Json package v12.0.3
- Go back and reinstall the GraphQL nuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhy `dotnet restore` brings dependency warnings only on RuntimeIdentifier:`win10-x64`.  `portable` runtime works normally.

Answer (score 1):

may be some one added a new project with new version and there may be some project with old version. upgrading all the projects to the same version would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem (NU1605) when publishing but I figured out was the runtime `linux-x64`. So I removed the runtime option and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where my project had package reference like this:

Package references:

- Package A
- Package B

  - Package A

So because project B reference package A, I just deleted package A from the main packages list and was left with Package B referencing Package A.
I rebuilt the solution and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when adding a Connected Service reference to an ASP.Net Webservice. Added this reference in project Nop.Plugin.SDE causing a reference to System.ServiceModel.Http 4.4.4 to be added, while it already was referencing project Nop.Services having a reference to System.ServiceModel.Http 4.7.0. The solution was to upgrade the reference to System.ServiceModel.Http to version 4.7.0 from project Nop.Plugin.SDE.

[image: Solution explorer after adding reference]

[image: Upgrade System.ServiceModel.Http from 4.4.4 to 4.7.0]

[image: Reference to System.ServiceMode.Http from Nop.Services]

Answer (score 0):

After going through all the advices above, and taking reference from the accepted answer from @Mert, what worked for me was **deleting the specific package that was causing the inconsistency**.

[image]

Inside package folder, visual studio very helpfully marks the package causing the issue with a yellow warning sign.

I deleted the package and used NuGet to install the appropriate version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me to solve the same problem temporary which happened to me recently. Later, I learnt it is something related to [how NuGet resolves package dependencies.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution)

According to Microsoft documentation "When the package graph for an application contains different versions of the same package, NuGet chooses the package that's closest to the application in the graph and ignores all others. This behavior allows an application to override any particular package version in the dependency graph." that is why it results in a downgrade of the package version. So, this rule is applied with a warning to alert the user.
[image: the application depends directly on Package B with a version constraint of >=2.0. The application also depends on Package A which in turn also depends on Package B, but with a >=1.0 constraint. Because the dependency on Package B 2.0 is nearer to the application in the graph, that version is used:]

This is a screenshot of the NugetPacKage manager of my code. As it is shown in the picture, the version of Serilog.Sink.Console of the Library and the Trading project are different.
[image]
I just uninstalled older one and installed new one. possibly, uninstallation of newer one will also work.

Actually, the solutions which were proposed in this page worked for me. I just wanted to share something that I found interesting, as an enthusiastic programmer. hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this Error and Just Upgrading the required Packages your Problem will be solved

You can upgrade the packages using NuGet Packages and from the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).