# Unexpected downgrade? Nuget Package Manager doesn't show latest version for Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting

Tags: .net-core, nuget, azure-service-fabric, nuget-package, service-fabric-remoting

I don't see Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting version 3.3.624 anymore:

[image: Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting version 3.3.622]

[image: Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting version 3.3.622]

My existing projects refer to 3.3.624:

[image: Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting version 3.3.624]

[image: Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Serices.Remoting version 3.3.624]

I get an NU1605 error Detected package downgrade.

Should I follow this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286990/error-nu1605-detected-package-downgrade) for this [NU1605 Detected package downgrade error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50323131/5587356)?

I am more curious as to why 3.3.624 just vanished!!!

Is downgrading existing references from 3.3.624 to 3.3.622 the only way to solve this prolbem? Or am I doing something wrong in referencing the versions?

Comment: I opened [GitHub issue 24021](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24021)  to ask why Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting version 3.3.624 is no longer available. Strangely, I seem to have version 3.3.624 available on one machine, but on my other machine I can install only 3.3.622.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions

> I am more curious as to why 3.3.624 just vanished!!!

and

> Is downgrading existing references from 3.3.624 to 3.3.622 the only way to solve this prolbem?

From MicahMcKittrick's response to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24021) I created:

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

So you'll have to downgrade Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting to 3.3.622, <del>the current latest version</del> or upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: SF team recently [released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2019/02/04/azure-service-fabric-6-4-refresh-release/) the version `x.x.624` and `x.x.622`of SF Runtime, Seems that the `.624` does not need new packages, the release details mentions only bugs fixes on windows, the new SDK should be `3.3.622.9590`. Looking on nuget, they just released a new version of packages `3.3.638`, might fix the issue with different versioning.