Unable to generate Unreal C++ project after upgrading to Visual Studio 17.12
Environment:

Unreal 5.4.4
Visual Studio 17.12 Community
Windows 11

I have a very annoying issue since i updated VS this morning. After several reinstallation following documentation on unreal and microsoft website + trying to reload configuration from an another computer via "load configuration" in Visual Studio Installer, i still have these errors when i try to generate a C++ project out of the Project Browser:
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.4/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="...UDEV.uproject" -game -rocket -progress -log="...UDEV/Saved/Logs/UnrealVersionSelector-2024.11.14-16.52.04.log"
Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
Building UnrealBuildTool with dotnet...
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.targets(4,5): warning : System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Options 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.http\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Http.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Http 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.MsBuild\EpicGames.MsBuild.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Build 17.12.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.MsBuild\EpicGames.MsBuild.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.IO.Redist 6.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.IoHash\EpicGames.IoHash.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Memory from 4.6.0 to 4.5.5. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.IoHash\EpicGames.IoHash.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.IoHash -> EpicGames.Core -> System.Memory (>= 4.6.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.IoHash\EpicGames.IoHash.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.IoHash -> System.Memory (>= 4.5.5) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Serialization\EpicGames.Serialization.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Memory from 4.6.0 to 4.5.5. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Serialization\EpicGames.Serialization.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Serialization -> EpicGames.IoHash -> EpicGames.Core -> System.Memory (>= 4.6.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Serialization\EpicGames.Serialization.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Serialization -> EpicGames.IoHash -> System.Memory (>= 4.5.5) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console from 9.0.0 to 6.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj : error NU1605:  UnrealBuildTool -> EpicGames.Core -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console (>= 9.0.0) 
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj : error NU1605:  UnrealBuildTool -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console (>= 6.0.0)
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly from 9.0.0 to 6.0.26. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> EpicGames.Core -> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly (>= 9.0.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly (>= 6.0.26) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from 9.0.0 to 6.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> EpicGames.Core -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 9.0.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 6.0.0) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.targets(4,5): warning : System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Options 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.http\9.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Http.targets(4,5): warning : Microsoft.Extensions.Http 9.0.0 doesn't support net6.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net8.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.MsBuild\EpicGames.MsBuild.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Build 17.12.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.MsBuild\EpicGames.MsBuild.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.IO.Redist 6.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.IoHash\EpicGames.IoHash.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Memory from 4.6.0 to 4.5.5. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.IoHash\EpicGames.IoHash.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.IoHash -> EpicGames.Core -> System.Memory (>= 4.6.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.IoHash\EpicGames.IoHash.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.IoHash -> System.Memory (>= 4.5.5) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Serialization\EpicGames.Serialization.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Memory from 4.6.0 to 4.5.5. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Serialization\EpicGames.Serialization.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Serialization -> EpicGames.IoHash -> EpicGames.Core -> System.Memory (>= 4.6.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Serialization\EpicGames.Serialization.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Serialization -> EpicGames.IoHash -> System.Memory (>= 4.5.5) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console from 9.0.0 to 6.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj : error NU1605:  UnrealBuildTool -> EpicGames.Core -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console (>= 9.0.0) 
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj : error NU1605:  UnrealBuildTool -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console (>= 6.0.0)
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly from 9.0.0 to 6.0.26. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> EpicGames.Core -> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly (>= 9.0.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly (>= 6.0.26) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from 9.0.0 to 6.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> EpicGames.Core -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 9.0.0)  [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\EpicGames.Horde\EpicGames.Horde.csproj : error NU1605:  EpicGames.Horde -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 6.0.0) [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.csproj]
    12 Warning(s)
    5 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.93
ERROR: Failed to build UnrealBuildTool.

Here is the VS configuration:
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.TSServer",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR",
    "Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.9.0",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.8.0",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp",
    "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.ClickOnce.Publish",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.DevelopmentTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.8.DeveloperTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.2022",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
    "Component.VisualStudio.GitHub.Copilot",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.6.0",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.22621",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DotNetModelBuilder",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WindowsAppSDK.Cs",
    "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11Sdk.WindowsPerformanceToolkit",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CppBuildInsights",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Vcpkg",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.20348",
    "Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Native",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WindowsAppSdkSupport.CSharp",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WindowsAppDevelopment.Prerequisites",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.HLSL",
    "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.TargetingPacks.Common",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools",
    "Component.Unreal.Ide",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame"
  ],
  "extensions": []
}

Does anyone has a clue on how to solve this?
Cheers

machine cleanup & reinstallation following documentation on unreal and microsoft website
reload configuration from an another computer via "load configuration" in Visual Studio Installer
adding <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> to UnrealBuildTool.csproj, but it only fixed the first part of the errors


Looks like there are some nuget dependencies mismatches. Does this relate to your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286990/error-nu1605-detected-package-downgrade/

From my original post on UE Dev Community:

I have encountered the same issue after trying to update “Vulnerable
packages” following by VS hint. I think it changed something in the UE
source files, so what helped me:
MY SOLUTION:

Go to Epic Games Launcher → Unreal Engine.
Find your engine version.
On the right from yellow “Launch” button there is dropdown menu
Choose “Verify” option

It will check all engine files for identity with the release ones and
reinstall required files.
Note: I have encountered “Queued” status, and it didn’t change.
Windows restart fixed it.

I hope it will help you.
Best regards.

And in case if you got into this trouble just the same way as I am, here's few things about it


I had something like 50 projects on my solution, and 48 of them is UE .Net programs. VS didn't liked versions of NuGet packages they had. This is where I have got in trouble, after upgrading them.



If you want to just have "Engine" and "Game" projects, follow this post on Dev Community: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/is-it-normal-to-have-about-50-projects-in-freshly-created-c-project-in-visual-studio-2022/1998178


I had same problem. I installed .NET 8 after uninstalling .NET6 from visual studio installer. And I disabled read only option of
UE_5.5\Engine\Source Directory. Then Unreal project build is works well. Additionally, my full path of UE is:
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.5\Engine\Source

Hope this works well with you.
Edit:
This Only works with UE 5.5. Sorry for confused the version. But UE 5.5 with VS 17.12 has similar NuGet problem too. So, this solution is work with UE 5.5.
If you want to use UE 5.4, Revert version of VS to 17.11. This is the only way I found. Sorry if this is not helpful.

I managed to recover my dev environment this way:
Steps:

Install Unreal 5.4.4
Install VisualStudio 17.12 for unreal (.Net desktop dev, Desktop dev C++, Windows app dev, Game dev C++)
Extra components :

Compilers, build tools:

MVSC v143 - VS 2022 ARM build tools (v14.38 - 17.8)
MVSC v143 - VS 2022 ARM64/ARM64EC build tools (v14.38 - 17.8)
MVSC v143 - VS 2022 x64/x86 build tools (v14.38 - 17.8)
MVSC v143 - VS 2022 x64/x86 build tools (v14.38 - 17.8)


SDKs, libraries:

C++ v14.38 (17.18) ALT for v143 build tools (x86 & x64)
C++ v14.38 (17.18) MFC for v143 build tools (x86 & x64)
(the extar libs can also be installed automatically once you open VS and click on the notification “Install extar module for your project” at the top right corner)




locate %appdata%\Unreal Engine\Unreal BuildTool\BuildConfiguration.xml and force the compiler configuration with these lines:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Configuration xmlns="https://www.unrealengine.com/BuildConfiguration">
        <WindowsPlatform>
            <CompilerVersion>14.38.33130</CompilerVersion>
            <ToolchainVersion>14.38.33130</ToolchainVersion>
        </WindowsPlatform>
    </Configuration>

The main thread for this issue is in unreal forum > https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/unable-to-generate-c-project-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-17-12-blocking/2122722
